# Java Parking System: Method to Retrieve List of Parking Transactions by Customer ID and Billing Month

Tags: java

This is my first post here and I'm trying to write a method for a class project.  The project is to write a parking system in Java. The method is supposed to return a list of parking transactions by customer ID and billing month.  Below is my attempt so far.  Eclipse lists a number of errors on line 5 which are listed below.
Error;

```
    Multiple markers at this line
        - Syntax error, insert ">" to complete ReferenceType1
        - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName
        - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
        - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
        - Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete 
         LocalVariableDeclaration
```

Old Code;

```
        //  Prints a list of transactions by customer id and month
            public void getMonthlyBillbyCustomerId(int searchId) {
                System.out.println("Your parking transactions for: ");
                for (Customer customer : listOfCustomers) {
                    int i=0; i < monthlyBillbByCustomerId.size(); i++);
                    if (customer.getCustomerId() == (searchId));
                    if (transaction.getParkingDate() == (searchMonth)
                    System.out.println((i+1) + ". Name: " + monthlyBillByCustomerId.get(i).getCustomerId() +
                        ", ID: " + listOfCustomers.get(i).getCustomerId()));
            }
        }
```

New Code;

```
         //  Prints a list of transactions by customer id and month
             public void getMonthlyBillbyCustomerId(int searchId) {
                 System.out.println("Your parking transactions for: ");
                 for (int i=0; i < monthlyBillByCustomerId.size(); i++) {
                     for (Customer customer : listOfCustomers) {
                         if (customer.getCustomerId() == (searchId) &&   Transaction.getParkingDate(searchTransactions) == (searchMonth)) {
                    System.out.println((i+1) + ". Name: " + monthlyBillByCustomerId.get(i).getCustomerId() +
                    ", ID: ");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `int i=0; i < monthlyBillbByCustomerId.size(); i++);`? It is a `for`?

Comment: This code has a lot of small problems. The `int i=0;` looks like it was meant to be a `for` loop? You have an extra `)` at the end of the line. Then the `f (customer.getCustomerId()` line doesn't do anything, and the line after it appears to be missing at least a `)`.

Comment: Yes, you are both correct, it is part a for loop.

Comment: Thank you both for your patience!  I'm obviously a beginner and I'm making the suggested changes now.

Comment: I think my problem is that I want a list of transactions that match a given month and my code isn't setup for that.